# Email Notification when file added to folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know very little about scripting, but I think what I want is possible. I would simply like to get an email notification when a file is added to a particular folder. I don't have any specific software, so I guess it would have to be a batch file or maybe VBS?

Comment: Which paert are you having difficulty with - the change-detection or the email-generation?

Comment: We use a piece of software called WatchDirectory to monitor folders and perform actions on those files.

Comment: I have a .vbs file that sends an email, but every script I find that is supposed to check for new files hasn't worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, in a batch-file with powershell enabled:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "emailUserName=dummyEmail@gmail.com"
set "emailPassword=dummyPassword"
set "target=yourEmail@email.com"
set "subject=File Changed"
FOR %%G IN (*) DO attrib -A "%%G"
:loop
set "body="
FOR %%G IN (*) DO (
    attrib "%%G" | findstr /B /L A 1>nul
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        echo "%%G"
        set "body=!body!^<br ^/^>%%G"
        attrib -A "%%G"
        )
    ) 2>nul
if not "%body%"=="" echo sending email
if not "%body%"=="" set "body=The following files have been changed:!body!"
if not "%body%"=="" powershell.exe -command "Send-MailMessage -From '!emailUserName!' -to '!target!' -Subject '!subject!' -Body '!body!' -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port '587' -UseSsl -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ('!emailUserName!', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '!emailPassword!' -AsPlainText -Force)))"
goto :loop
```

For this to work, you need to create a dummy gmail acount that will send the email. This supports HTML tags in the body, as shown in the example.

Note that this doesn't work on deletion of files, only changes and new files.

Comment: @dingram10 updated so it now sends email notifications on changes in the folder the batch-file is in.

Comment: @dingram10 If my answer solved your problem, you should consider clicking the check to the left of it so people searching on google for the same problem can find it. See [this](//stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for why this is important.

Comment: It does work! The only change I made was setting the server for our exchange server and using an internal email address. The only other change I might make would be if there was a way to have it run in the background, without a command prompt window. But, that is purely a preference.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have information about your email server? What version of Windows and Powershell do you have?

This short Powershell script works in my environment:

```
$folder = "D:\"
$mailserver = "your.mailserver.your.company"
$recipient = "your.email@your.company"

$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder -Property @{
   IncludeSubdirectories = $true
   NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName'
}

$created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {
   $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
   $s = New-Object System.Security.SecureString
   $anon = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON", $s)
   Send-MailMessage -To $recipient `
                    -From "alerts@your.company" `
                    -Subject “File Creation Event” `
                    -Body "A file was created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)" `
                    -SmtpServer $mailserver `
                    -Credential $anon
}
```

Stop the alerts with this:

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier Created -Force
```

Comment: I copied that script into a notepad file, changed the appropriate information, and saved it as a .ps1 on my DC (2008R2). Then I right clicked and Ran with PowerShell. I received no notification after adding a file.
Did I miss anything? Also, does the fact that the new filed are scanned into that folder (pdf) make a difference?

Comment: Not sure about the version of PowerShell, but I would like to run it on Server 2008 R2. Alternately, I could run it from a workstation with Windows 7.
We have an exchange server. I have both the name and IP.

Answer (score 0):

I built my solution based on what @xXhRQ8sD2L7Z contributed. But I was getting multiple emails as I tested, a new one for every time I ran the register script. The Unregister line was not working:

```
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier Created -Force
```

So I found this: [Unregister a registered filewatcher event does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033901/unregister-a-registered-filewatcher-event-does-not-work)

```
    Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "filechanged" | Unregister-Event
```

but it still wasn't working, so I ran `Get-EventSubscriber` by itself and got a list of the Subscriptions for the Event and found that, in my case, the `-SourceIdentifier` was a GUID. With that understanding, I grabbed each individual GUID and proceeded to unregister them. (I could've looped through them, but I will only use this once, probably. Plus, I had only created the subscription 6 times before I realized what was happening)

This eliminated all of the extra emails i received every time I tested.

```
    Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier "<very long GUID>" | Unregister-Event
```

Then I wanted to send to multiple recipients, so i found this: [Powershell send-mailmessage - email to multiple recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241816/powershell-send-mailmessage-email-to-multiple-recipients)

```
    $recipients = "<User1@domain.com>", "<User2@domain.com>"
```

You can also use email distribution groups.